# Displaying just one new/current post per category in homepage

Tags: categories

I want to displaying only one new/current post per category in homepage. For example, there is 3 post with category **A**, and i want the old post from category **A** is replaced with the new post from category **A** in homepage, and the old post is just gone but not deleted. This also same for other categories.

I'm using `pre_get_posts` to approach this, but mine is just display one category only and the other is not.

Here's my code

```
function my_home_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', -1 );

        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1);
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_home_category' );
```

I know my code is not good, and i gladly appreciated any help that come to mind. thanks

Comment: You can't do this with a single query. You will need to get a list of categories, loop over them, and query 1 post from each, separately.

Answer (score 0):

As you are not comfortable with coding, you can try using [Recent Posts Widget Extended](https://wordpress.org/plugins/recent-posts-widget-extended/) plugin. It allows you to specify the number of posts per category that you want to be displayed.

Follow these steps:

1. Install and activate the plugin.
2. Head to **Appearance > Widgets**. Add **Recent Posts Extended** widget
   to your sidebar.
3. The widget menu will expand to show its settings. Here, you can
   choose your desired category and specify the number of posts to
   show.
4. Finally, click on the **Save** button to store your widget settings.